# Can I use a non-constant value to calculate the effective address in a loop?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm

In a loop called filter, I want to calculate the address, where RSI should be saved by the save function, based on an offset which is subtracted from RBP in every itteration:
The part of the code containing the problem is a rather long loop, but I'm only pasting the problematic part here.
I use nasm assembler, on ubuntu 2204.

```
code:
filter:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    sub rsp, 128

    mov [rbp], 1 ; a multiplier which when multiplied by the constant 8, gives me     ; the offset
    ; it must also be incremented by save.

save: ; this function must calculate the correct address to mov RSI to, and do it
    push rdx ; preserve it
    mov rdx, [rbp] ; get the multiplier in a register
    mult rdx, 8 ; here's the offset
    mov [rbp-rdx], rsi ; this line produces "invalid effective address" error
    inc rdx ; inc the offset so next time when the save function is called, RSI 
    ; would get saved below the current address and not overwrite it
    mov [rbp], rdx ; put the incremented multiplier back
    ret
```

Comment: x86 addressing modes can only add and left-shift by 0 to 3.  Use `neg rdx` / `mov [rbp + rdx*8], rsi`.  Or start with a `-1` offset and use `dec` instead of `inc`.

Comment: Also, `mult` isn't an x86 instruction, maybe you meant `imul rdx, [rbp], 8`.  And generally don't save/restore *every* register, just let RDX be destroyed by this function.  Also of course that `ret` won't work since RSP is no longer pointing at the return address, I assume that was just an oversight in cutting this down to a [mcve]

Comment: (Also, `shl rdx, 3` if you want to multiply a register by 8.  Don't use multiply instructions for powers of 2.  Only worth considering for `imul rdx, [rbp], -8` or something if you really want to be counting upwards.  Or I guess `imul rcx, rdx, -8` since you want the old RDX value in a reg to inc and store.  Currently you're storing `var = var * 8 + 1`.  But in this case just use a scale factor in the addressing mode so you don't have to produce a scaled copy in another register.  Or `inc` / `mov [rbp], rdx` / `shl rdx,3` to scale after updating memory.)

Comment: Also, `[rbp]` points at the saved RBP value from `push rbp`.  You probably want `[rbp-8]` or something.  Or just `[rsp]` after reserving some stack space.  Or keep your counter in a register instead of memory at all.

Comment: All tested, and all true!